# Angular Subscribe to Observable after URL request

Tags: angular

excuse my lingo if I'm not using the correct vocabulary for Subjects and Observables.

Anyway, what I'd like to do is get a list of images when subscribing to newImages. Currently in the console my response is

[]

[3]

[7]

[9]

where each number is the length of the array. This is correct. 9 is the correct length array and I'm getting my image list.

But! I would just like the console to print out [9]. I'm not sure why I subscribe 4 times.

How would I delay the subscription until the forEach loop finishes so I'm not subscribing multiple times?

I'm afraid when trying to display the images in my HTML component I could run into problems.

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private data: Masterdata) {   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message);
  }

  getBabies() {
    this.data.getBabiesById().subscribe(
      data => {
      this.BabiesRooms = data;

      data.forEach((element) => {
        this.data.getImagesByBabyId(String(element.idbabyroom)).subscribe();
      });
      });

    console.log("ASDF");
      this.data.newImages.subscribe(data => console.log(data));

  }
}
```

EDIT: Let me rephrase it a litte. There are two subscriptions in the method getBabies().

I only want the second subscription to be called after the first subscription is complete.

Comment: Instead of looping through `data`, why not just get `data[data.length - 1]`?

Comment: So each idbabyroom makes a separate URL call.

Comment: Okay, so you want to make all of the calls, but you only care about the final response?

Comment: Correct. So pretty much I want the first subscription to finish before the second subscription is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use forkjoin to make that happen:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
  this._myService.makeRequest('Request One', 2000),
  this._myService.makeRequest('Request Two', 1000),
  this._myService.makeRequest('Request Three', 3000)
)
.subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
  this.propOne = res1;
  this.propTwo = res2;
  this.propThree = res3;
});
```

Also You can make use of Rxjs flatMap for doing the same:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
getBabies() {
    return this.data.getBabiesById().do(response => {
        // do something with above response
        this.BabiesRooms = response;
    }).flatMap(response => {
        response.forEach((element) => {
            this.data.getImagesByBabyId(String(element.idbabyroom)).subscribe();
        });
    })


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can make use of `rxjs` forkJoin. And instead of `forEach` use the map to store the list in an array. Below is the what you should try

```
  let someVar = data.map((element) => {
     return this.data.getImagesByBabyId(String(element.idbabyroom));
    });
  });

 const result = forkJoin(someVar)
       .subscribe(res => {
    // Here you will get the result in the form of array
    // such as
    // console.log(res[0], 'res[0]') is first res of subscription stored in array and so on...
    // console.log(res[1], 'res[1]')
    // console.log(res[res.length - 1]) // to get the last item
  })
```

for detailed information about [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)