# Angular RxJs level up during looping an array

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have an http get request to get an array like

```js
[
  {name: 'name1', id: 1, specialProp: [] },
  {name: 'name2', id: 2, specialProp: [] }
]
```

I need to get each of array items, take an id and send a request to server to get some information. The results should be written into the property `specialProp`. After that I need to take the array of the prop `specialProp` and for each item get some data, put it into `anotherSpecialProp`. In the end I should have the final array like

```js
[
  {name: 'name1', id: 1, specialProp: [
    {name: 'c', anotherSpecialProp: []}, 
    {name: 'd', anotherSpecialProp: []}
  ]},

  {name: 'name2', id: 2, specialProp: [
    {name: 'a', anotherSpecialProp: []},
    {name: 'b', anotherSpecialProp: []}
  ]}
]
```

I have the code:

```js
this.http.get(url)
  .pipe(
    switchMap((mainItemArr: any) => from(mainItemArr)),
    mergeMap((mainItem: any): any => {
      return this.getSomeInfo(mainItem.Id) //another http get request
        .pipe(
          map((data: any): any => {
            return Object.assign(mainItem, { specialProp: data })
          }),
          switchMap((mainItemArr: any): any => from(mainItemArr.specialProp)),
          concatMap((item: any): any => {
            return this.getSomeOtherInfo(item.Id) // one more http get request
              .pipe(
                map((data: any): any => Object.assign({}, task, { anotherSpecialProp: data }))
              )
          }),
        )
    })
  )
```

So in subscribe I receive just the items, not the whole mainItemArr.
Could anyone please assist me with the issue?:)

Comment: please, put your code between \``` lang-js and \``` for better readability. See ["formatting help"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for details

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53109081/9386929

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Subscribe to Observable after URL request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53108252/angular-subscribe-to-observable-after-url-request)

Comment: @nircraft, I have checked the articles, but I can not get your point, how the article could help me(((( Perhaps, you could provide me with more details of your answer?

I receive the new data, but I can not get the initial array, as the stream gives me the last stream elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main trick is to use `map` to merge scoped property with request result.

Here's a rough example how to achieve this for the first level (`specialProp`):

```ts
this.http.get(url).pipe(
  mergeMap(mainItemArr => {
    // forkJoin will wait for each request to complete
    return forkJoin(
      // make a subsequent request for each item in mainItemArr
      mainItemArr.map(mainItem => {
        return this.getSomeInfo(mainItem.Id).pipe(
          // merge getSomeInfo result with the mainItem
          map(someInfo => {
            return {
              ...mainItem,
              specialProp: someInfo
            };
          })
        )
      })
    )
  })
)
```

For the `anotherSpecialProp` requests — you'll need to go one level deeper.

In a real world application I'd suggest splitting those subsequent calls into separate functions/methods.

***NOTE***:

You don't need turning array into Observable:

```js
mergeMap(mainArray => mainArray)
```

Instead you might keep it in the JS scope and do subsequent requests in the `mergeMap`, e.g.:

```js
mergeMap(mainArray => {
  // making sub requests here
})
```

Using `mergeMap` to turn array into Observable should work too, though it might be more confusing when diving 1 level deeper, imho. Anyway, the `map` does the main trick.

Hope this helps

Comment: That was really helpfull and relevant answer. Worked for my similar usecase

Answer (score 3):

If I get it right, what you need to do is the following:

- fetch the initial array from back end
- for each element of the array, call `getSomeInfo` and store the result, which should be an array, into the `specialProp` property
- then, for each entry in the `specialProp` array, you want to call the `getSomeOtherInfo` method, fetch some more data and store it into a property called `anotherSpecialProp`

If all this is true, then you can try something along these lines

```
getArray()
.pipe(
    mergeMap(mainArray => mainArray),  // unwind the array received
    switchMap(mainItem => getSomeInfo(mainItem.id) // fetch the first set of info from backend
        .pipe(
            tap(someInfo => {
                mainItem['specialProp'] = someInfo; // wrote someInfo into specialProp property
            }),
            mergeMap(specialProps => specialProps), // unwind the array of specialProps
            switchMap(specialProp => getSomeOtherInfo(specialProp.name) // for each specialProp fetch the additional data
                .pipe(
                    tap(someOtherInfo => {
                        specialProp['anotherSpecialProp'] = someOtherInfo // store additional data into anotherSpecialProp property
                    })
                )
            ),
            toArray(), // rewind the array of  specialProps and return it
            map(() => mainItem)
        )
    ),
    toArray() // rewind the array of mainItems and return it
)
```

The thing you may want to notice is the use of `mergeMap` with an Array, e.g. `mergeMap(mainArray => mainArray)`.

`mergeMap` accepts as input a function which returns an **ObservableInput**. An Array is an **ObservableInput** which emits all of its items synchronously before ***completing***. So, passing a function which returns an Array to `mergeMap` means to emit all the elements of the Array.

You can find an example of the [above example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-imchaa?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: Thank you very much, guys! Your answers were very useful! It allowed me to get some understanding RxJs as I am a newbie in RxJs and a step to dive deeper into this library! thank you!